# Track drags IF a key is down in RXJS

Tags: dom, rxjs

I want to allow the user to drag something IF a key is down. Its ok if they let up the key WHILE they are dragging but the can't INITIATE the drag if the key is up.

I have something that works -- BUT it feels "forced." It feels like I can do more "clever" combination of the two sets of observers than what I have here.

Also, there are situations where I want to STOP observing, both the keys, and the mouse; I can unsub to the mouse observer, but the key observer is hidden in closure. Any suggestions?

```js
class EventQueue {
  /**
   * This event returns an emitter that emits an observer for every drag sequence,
   * _IF_ a given key is down __when__ the drag starts.
   */
  static keyDownAndDragObserver(window: Window, key: string) {
    const keyUpObserver = fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(window, 'keyup') // listen for any keyups
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => { // only listen for the key
          return event.key === key
        }),
        map(() => false)
      );
    const keyDownObserver = fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(window, 'keydown').pipe(
      filter((event) => { // only listen for the key
        return event.key === key && !event.repeat
      }),
      map(() => true)
    );

    let isDown = false;
    function setIsDown(n) {
      isDown = n;
    }
    keyDownObserver.subscribe(setIsDown);
    keyUpObserver.subscribe(setIsDown);

    const mouseUpObs = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(window, 'mouseup');
    const mouseMoveObs = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(window, 'mousemove');
    const mouseDownObs = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(window, 'mousedown');

    // console.log('EQ got keyEvent: ', ke.key)
    return mouseDownObs.pipe( // whenever we press mouse down
      filter(() => isDown),
      switchMap((de) => {
          console.log('EQ: mouseDown at ', de.x, de.y)
          return mouseMoveObs
            .pipe( // each time we move a cursor
              map((e) => {
                return { type: 'mousemove', x: e.x, y: e.y }
              }),
              takeUntil(mouseUpObs) // but only until we release the mouse button
            )
        } // end mouseMoveObs.pipe
      ) // end switchMap (inner)
    ) // end mouseDownObs.pipe
  }
}

export default EventQueue
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to explicitly subscribe to your `keyUpObs` and `keyDownObs` only to set a value (*actually those subscriptions aren't being cleaned up, which is bad news*).  You can simply create a combined observable that emits the boolean when the corresponding event occurs:

```js
const keyIsDown = merge(keyUpObs, keyDownObs);
```

I think it will make the code a little easier to follow if you define your drag behavior has its own observable:

```js
const dragObs = mouseDownObs.pipe(
  switchMap(() => mouseMoveObs),
  map(({x, y}) => ({ type: 'mousemove', x, y })),
  takeUntil(mouseUpObs)
);
```

Now to return your "drag while keydown" behavior:

```js
return keyIsDown.pipe(
  exhaustMap(keyIsDown => keyIsDown ? dragObs : EMPTY)
);
```

Here we use `exhaustMap` instead of `switchMap` in order to ignore emissions from `keyIsDown` while our `dragObs` is still in progress.  This allows drag events to continue to be emitted even after the key has been released.

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76285498?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts).

Comment: This has a lot of good things going and its really clean, thanks. 

_however_ there are a few key things absent -- here is a fork I did to tweak it a little:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76285498-hcaviw?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts,helpers.ts

1.  There's no "we are done" indicator at the end o a mousemove to let you know that the drag is complete.
2.  the mouseDown info needs to be embedded, as i've done int he fork
3.  it appears you have to "pump prime" it by putting the spacebar down and up once before it "kicks in". 

Any thoughts?